# Object detection using YOLO3

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I am working on training a model on the DeepFashion dataset with two classes including (upper cloth and lower cloth). The problem with the dataset is that it uses just one bounding box for each image. However, in some cases, the image includes both classes.

I am still not sure whether, in the prediction phase, the trained model using such a dataset is able to return two bounding boxes for images including both top and lower clothes. Any idea?

Comment: yes it is possible to detect multiple classes in 1 image even though the dataset only contains 1 label per image

Answer (score 1):

This would work no worries, you can try few examples of common objects in the web page here first -

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb